# installing geckodriver only using terminal

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am using a headless ubuntu, and want to install latest geckodriver.
So I must install by entering a command line.
my ubuntu is 14.04 trusty.

But, I don't know the command to install geckodriver.
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/

and here are many versions of geckodriver. 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
I guess I have to download linux32.tar.gz one.

Do I have to include the url of github to write a installing command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run these the commands:

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.18.0/geckodriver-v0.18.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

(You can find the download URL to the latest release of geckodriver on [Github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).)

Extract the file with

```
tar -xvzf geckodriver*
```

Make it executable (note this shouldn't be necessary, unless the unzipped file doesn't have the execute bits set):

```
chmod +x geckodriver
```

Add the driver to your PATH in `~/.bashrc` so other tools can find it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path-to-extracted-file/geckodrive
```

Answer (score 13):

**Step1 : Download Gecko Driver**

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.26.0/geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

**Step2: Unzip tar file**

```
sudo tar -xvf geckodriver-v0.26.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

**Step3: Move Gecko Driver to Binary Location**

```
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

**Step4: Change Current Directory to Binary Location**

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
```

**Step5: Make Executable Permission to 'geckodriver'**

```
sudo chmod +x geckodriver
```

> Gecko Driver Setup Successfull

Answer (score 11):

You can install *geckodriver* by a single command in Ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver`

Other distributions may need another approach.

Comment: I tried every other solution (I even compiled the driver) but wasn't able to install it on raspberry-pi. This worked like a charm!

Comment: error : Unable to locate package firefox-geckodriver . debian 11

Answer (score 0):

If Rust is available, geckodriver can be installed as follows:

```bash
cargo install geckodriver
```